# How to redirect to angular app from another website with data?

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I have a WordPress app, now I want to send the user from this WordPress app to my angular app with some data,

I can not use the query string to pass data for cosmetic reasons.

Comment: you can store the data in some table in a dbs of Worpress and read from Angular. Another way is create a index.html (using php) and add in `<script>` the variables you need from angular. In Angular use "declare" to allow compiled the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing [this](https://jcubic.wordpress.com/2014/06/20/cross-domain-localstorage/#:%7E:text=As%20you%20may%20know%2C%20LocalStorage%20is%20domain%20based.&text=Basically%20to%20have%20Cross%2DDomain,set%20that%20value%20of%20localStorage.),

created a route in angular and made the component listen to window messages and on the reception of the message component saved it to localStorage.

```
ngOnInit(){
    window.onmessage = function(e) {
      if( !e.data || e.origin !== "http://theWordpressSite" ) return;
      var payload = JSON.parse(e.data);
      localStorage.setItem(payload.key, JSON.stringify(payload.data));
    };
  }
```

then used a hidden Iframe in the other site to open this angular route now on the desired event we can pass the message to this angular component

```
<button onclick="sendDataTo()">CLICK ME</button>
<iframe id="sendMessageToThis" style="display: none;" src="http://angularWebsite.com/localStorageUtility"
   frameborder="0"></iframe>
<script>
   var sendDataTo = function () {
       var win = document.getElementById('sendMessageToThis').contentWindow;
       var obj = {
           name: "Jack"
       };
       win.postMessage(JSON.stringify({ key: 'storage', data: obj }), "*");
   };
   
</script>
```